# How to Set Up A Form Submission System In Rails That Handles Many Different Fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm trying to set up a page in Ruby on Rails which accepts a lot of information from the user via forms then saves it (& also allows fields to be editable). I've set up forms before but only for a single title/content form, what I want will be a page that will have a form for:

Personal Details: Name, Age, Contact Details

Company Details: Name, Age, Contact Details

I'm not sure at all how to do this, if anyone could link me to a guide that explains how to do this or can explain it to me it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you check official guides and documentations? 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html  And 

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Answer (score 0):

For such a task you can just use scaffold
`rails g scaffold User age name street zip company_name etc..` 
Type this into your console

This will create a complete scaffold for you. You can create and edit your form. 
It's a good way to start if you have no other idea.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have "Company" in a separate model. If so, you need something similar to this code. Your controller will need to initiate both @user and @company.

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @user %>

  <h3>Yourself</h3>
  <%= f.label :first_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :last_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :age%>
  <%= f.text_field :age, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

  <h3>Your Company</h3>
  <%= fields_for(@company) do |c| %>
    <%= c.label :name %>
    <%= c.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= c.label :age%>
    <%= c.text_field :age, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= c.label :email %>
    <%= c.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```